Module not found: Can't resolve '@/src/components/layout/Header'

Failed to compile
Next.js (14.2.4) ./src/app/layout.js:3:1 Module not found: Can't
resolve '@/src/components/layout/Header'

The problem occurred out of nowhere 2 days ago the code was working fine and yesterday it started giving me this error.

Error: https://i.sstatic.net/XNSroLcg.png
Files: https://i.sstatic.net/v89ycKio.png
Header https://i.sstatic.net/wnBgUmY8.png

The last thing I did was I linked it to MongoDB, I tried deleting .next, node_modules, updating...

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Make sure that jsconfig.json is configured correctly with Module Path Aliases

Have you tried,
instead of:
import Header from "@/src/components/layout/Header";

do this:
import Header from "../components/layout/Header";

Do the other imports work? Can they be resolved? Or is it only the Header component. Can you provide a more detailed description of the enviroment and maybe produce a minimal reproducer, which we can look into?
